# AWS OpenSearch Authenticate with Master User

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, opensearch

I want to connect to open search to upload a new document using AWS. I am currently using a master user but I am unable to figure out how to authenticate using my master user credentials. All the examples I find assume a IAM user.